# Audio async when concatenating two videos

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am concatenating two videos (mp4 files) using ffmpeg command. 
The resulted video file creates issue with audio. The video frames lags in comparison with audio.

I have tried using "aresample" and "apad" properties of ffmpeg to tackle the issue but it didn't resolved the issue.

Command used for concat 2 mp4 files is as follows :-

ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i samplefilepath1.txt -c copy concat.mp4

samplefilepath1.txt contains path of both sample videos which needs to be concatenated:-

file sample1.mp4 (filepath 1)

file sample2.mp4 (filepath 2)

The video frames lags in comparison with audio.

Here is the link where you can find all three videos(sample and result videos)

https://gofile.io/?c=nXJckX

Comment: Link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 original sources are with a constant frame rate but the original frame rate was variable.

The concat.mp4 file is in Variable Frame Rate (VFR) instead of constant like 30 fps for the 2 sources files.

Try to add frame rate like below :

`ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i samplefilepath1.txt -r 30 -c copy concat.mp4`

Comment: I have tried adding frame rate in concat command but async problem is still there.